# update recyclerview contents fail in the bottom sheet

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, bottom-sheet

I want to change the list contents in a bottom sheet view though click event, but I only got empty sheet. Here is a demo modified from BottomSheetSample(github.com/niravkalola/BottomSheetSample).

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.nkdroid.bottomsheetsample;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    ItemAdapter.ItemListener {

private Button btnView, btnDialog;
BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
private BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;
private ItemAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    btnDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(createItems());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

    btnDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showBottomSheetDialog();
        }
    });

    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(createItems(), this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}


private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
    if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }

    mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet, null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(createItems(), new ItemAdapter.ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Item item) {
            if (mBottomSheetDialog != null) {
                mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }));

    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
    mBottomSheetDialog.show();
    mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mBottomSheetDialog = null;
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mAdapter.setListener(null);
}

public List<Item> createItems() {
    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Item(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Item 1"+ r.nextInt(100)));
    items.add(new Item(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Item 2"));
    items.add(new Item(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Item 3"));
    items.add(new Item(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Item 4"));
    return items;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(Item item) {
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}

}
```

**ItemAdapter.java:**

```
package com.nkdroid.bottomsheetsample;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Item> mItems;
private ItemListener mListener;

public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items, ItemListener listener) {
    mItems = items;
    mListener = listener;
}

public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items) {
    mItems = items;
}

public void setListener(ItemListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(mItems.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;
    public Item item;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void setData(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        imageView.setImageResource(item.getDrawableResource());
        textView.setText(item.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    }
}

public interface ItemListener {
    void onItemClick(Item item);
}
}
```

Here are the capture after click *show view* button for the first and second time:
[first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TZCw.png)
[second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW3WY.png)

Comment: If you press the 'recents' button on your phone and open another app, then press it again and go back to your app. Do the items in your RecyclerView appear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fixed in 24.0.0 i.e. the recyclerView gets updated. But if you are using wrap_content on the bottomsheet as well as recyclerview you will have to use this so that the bottomsheet height is calculated properly.

```
  bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if(newState==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
                    bottomSheet.requestLayout();

                    /*or
                     recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                     recyclerView.requestLayout();*/

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
```

If you want to work with earlier versions use

```
 bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if(newState==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
                    bottomSheet.requestLayout();
                    bottomSheet.invalidate();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Using the suggested callback works. notifyDataSetChanged now has the expected effect. Thanks

Comment: bottomSheet.requestLayout(); bottomSheet.invalidate(); really helps then placed in the callback. Thank you!